# Why resize uploaded images on website

Tags: html, image-uploading, image-upload

I have a website where people can upload images. I have seen that a lot of sites scale down images to thumbnail size and show that on a search page for example, until the user actually clicks on one to view it in full size.

Why is it good practice to generate a thumbnail version of an uploaded image? Why not just use `img` tag with set height and width?

**[EDIT]:** After reading a few answers, I realised that I have probably phrased my question poorly. So, what I mean is, are the images downloaded in full size, even if they have a size specified in CSS? Are they scaled down at rendering after the page has finsihed loading?

Thanks!

Comment: Stack Overflow is not for these types of questions.  Anyways, they are done to decrease page load speeds.  This is especially important when images are not lazy loaded.  Changing the img width and height does not decrease the size of the image being sent to the client.

Comment: 100 images * 7 mb = 700 mb download... 100 *.03 mb = 3 mb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Are the images downloaded in full size, even if they have a size specified in CSS?

Yes images will be downloaded in origin size (full size). CSS only changes view of image not main image file.

> Are they scaled down at rendering after the page has finsihed loading?

No, except when there is a script to do such job.

Answer (score 1):

Larger images have larger file sizes.  If you have 1MB images but only need to show thumbnails that might be 10KB in size, you'll be saving 99% of your bandwidth by only showing the full images when required.

In addition to bandwidth, clients often have limited memory... think of mobile devices.  Plus, the CPU required to handle them during scrolling and what not.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the img tag with width and height, that picture is still the original, the data size does not change (it only looks smaller in your browser).

If you have thumbnails, those thumbnails are smaller in data size but usually somewhere on your page you link them to the original with bigger data size.

If the user downloads the thumbnail, he'll get the small sized picture, if he downloads the original, he gets the big sized.
Note: A thumbnail is a different picture than the original.

Answer (score 0):

Smaller image has smaller size = faster loading.

When user actually want to see image, you open actual image and it may wait for load.

If you have several posts on search and each has image, thumbnails will be much faster to load than original images.

If you scale down original image with css (set width and height) it will still need to load original image first.